# Certificate vs secret - What to use at azure app registration?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to use the Microsft Graph API to get informations from the azure active directory. For this I need an access token, which is issued based on a secret or certificate.

In the azure portal the use of a certificate is recommended.
What are the reasons for using a certificate? Is the use of a certificate more secure than a secret?

What type of certificate can and should be stored? How can it be generated?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: this provides a good primer in general about password ("secret" in this case) vs certificates https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3627/250192

Answer (score 1):

> What are the reasons for using a certificate? Is the use of a
> certificate more secure than a secret?

Yes, Certificate is more secure than Secret, thus it is more complex and more expensive.
You could refer to the [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/certificate-based-authentication-vs-username-and-password-authentication/3627#3627) in silent's comment.

> What type of certificate can and should be stored? How can it be
> generated?

File Type: `.cer`, `.pem`, `.crt`

Read details about the format of [certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials). Here is how to craft a signed client assertion:

```
string Encode(byte[] arg)
{
    char Base64PadCharacter = '=';
    char Base64Character62 = '+';
    char Base64Character63 = '/';
    char Base64UrlCharacter62 = '-';
    char Base64UrlCharacter63 = '_';

    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(arg);
    s = s.Split(Base64PadCharacter)[0]; // RemoveAccount any trailing padding
    s = s.Replace(Base64Character62, Base64UrlCharacter62); // 62nd char of encoding
    s = s.Replace(Base64Character63, Base64UrlCharacter63); // 63rd char of encoding

    return s;
}

string GetSignedClientAssertion()
{
    //Signing with SHA-256
    string rsaSha256Signature = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
     X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("Certificate.pfx", "Password", X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet);

    //Create RSACryptoServiceProvider
    var x509Key = new X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(certificate);
    var privateKeyXmlParams = certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKeyXmlParams);

    //alg represents the desired signing algorithm, which is SHA-256 in this case
    //kid represents the certificate thumbprint
    var header = new Dictionary<string, string>()
         {
              { "alg", "RS256"},
              { "kid", Encode(Certificate.GetCertHash()) }
         };

    //Please see the previous code snippet on how to craft claims for the GetClaims() method
    string token = Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JObject.FromObject(header).ToString())) + "." + Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JObject.FromObject(GetClaims())));

    string signature = Encode(rsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token), new SHA256Cng()));
    string signedClientAssertion = string.Concat(token, ".", signature);
    return signedClientAssertion;
}

private static IDictionary<string, string> GetClaims()
{
      //aud = https://login.microsoftonline.com/ + Tenant ID + /v2.0
      string aud = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0";

      string ConfidentialClientID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" //client id
      const uint JwtToAadLifetimeInSeconds = 60 * 10; // Ten minutes
      DateTime validFrom = DateTime.UtcNow;
      var nbf = ConvertToTimeT(validFrom);
      var exp = ConvertToTimeT(validFrom + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(JwtToAadLifetimeInSeconds));

      return new Dictionary<string, string>()
           {
                { "aud", aud },
                { "exp", exp.ToString() },
                { "iss", ConfidentialClientID },
                { "jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString() },
                { "nbf", nbf.ToString() },
                { "sub", ConfidentialClientID }
            };
}
```

Or using Powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/certificate-based-authentication#create-a-self-signed-certificate